# Convert haskell record insert function to a more generic type

Tags: haskell, insert, record

I have a sample type like this:

```
data Sample_Type = Sample_Type { field1 :: Int,
                                 field2 :: Int,
                                 field3 :: [Int]
                               } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I'm using this function to append `field3` list inside the record:

```
insertPlan :: [Sample_Type] -> Sample_Type -> Int -> [Sample_Type]
insertPlan [] _ _ = []
insertPlan (x:xs) y b = if (x == y)
                        then (y {field3 = b:(field3 y)}):xs
                        else x:(insertPlan xs y b)
```

I'm trying to convert the above function to a more generic form (since I have many records datatype with one list in it which needs to be updated).

I came up with following piece of code, but that doesn't work (obviously):

```
insertVariant :: [a] -> a -> (a -> [Int]) -> Int -> [a]
insertVariant (x:xs) a f b  = if (x == a)
                              then (a {f = b:(f a)}):xs
                              else x:(insertVariant xs a b)
```

Any good way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Use [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeclasses are one solution, but you'll need the `MultiParamTypeClasses` extension:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Insertable i a where
    insertInto :: i -> a -> i


data SampleType = SampleType
    { field1 :: Int
    , field2 :: Int
    , field3 :: [Int]
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Insertable SampleType Int where
    insertInto (SampleType f1 f2 f3) x = SampleType f1 f2 (x:f3)

data MyType = MyType
    { mtField1 :: String
    , mtField2 :: [String]
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Insertable MyType String where
    insertInto (MyType f1 f2) x = MyType f1 (x:f2)

insertPlan :: (Eq i, Insertable i a) => [i] -> i -> a -> [i]
insertPlan [] _ _ = []
insertPlan (x:xs) y b =
    if x == y
        then insertInto y b : xs
        else x : insertPlan xs y b


main = do
    let s = SampleType 1 2 [1..5]
        m = MyType "Testing" ["world"]
    print $ insertPlan [s] s (6 :: Int)
    print $ insertPlan [m] m "Hello"
```

A few things to note:

1. `FlexibleInstances` is for `instance MyType String` because `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, so the compiler rejects it without this extension.
2. I had to specify the type of `6`, because otherwise the compiler can't figure out what type `6` is supposed to be.
3. You could write this without `MultiParamTypeClasses`, but then your `insertInto` couldn't type-check against what was being inserted into the list.  There are other solutions, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
data Sample_Type = Sample_Type { field1 :: Int,
                                 field2 :: Int,
                                 field3 :: [Int]
                               } deriving (Show, Eq)



insertVariant :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> (a -> Int -> a) -> Int -> [a]
insertVariant l a f i = map (\x -> if x == a then f x i else x) l

main = print $ insertVariant [Sample_Type 1 2 []] (Sample_Type 1 2 []) (\s i -> s {field3 = i:(field3 s)}) 10
```

You can get rid of `(\s i -> s {field3 = i:(field3 s)})` by using Lens package.
A lens will give you the getter and setter for the record fields so that you can pass a lens for `(a -> Int -> a)` parameter